# how to remove any view from main view and then add at same place in iphone application

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview

I want to remove the view from screen when any method is loaded and again add when method is finished is there any method to do that ,i am doing using hidden property but it is not working for some times.
any other method to do this.

here is the link of code class it is large that is why i have given link.

http://codepad.org/orZE8xZm

Comment: Give the proper link to your code

Comment: @Mohith here is the proper link for code http://codepad.org/orZE8xZm

Comment: @Mohith did you check the code when i click graphAction button i am hidding view but they do not hide it may due to showupdates button code where we are setting frame i think

Comment: Sorry mate, but your code is not clear to me. I dont really understand what you are trying to hide and unhide there

Comment: i want to hide the views first to thirteen problem is that when screen is loaded and i click graphButtonAction then the all views are hidden but when i press showUpdateAction and then press graphAction then it does not hide

Comment: why dont you remove views using  removeFromSuperview  and add them back using addSubview methods

Comment: then it is crashing can you write how to remove and again add

Answer (score 2):

you can change alpha to zero to remove & vice versa

```
        [TwelveView setFrame:CGRectMake(720,300,50,-height12)];
```

Comment: it is also working but in view did only here is my code which i am using condition is that in view did load i have add these subViews and in another method later i set their frames so might be due to this while in view load it is working and not working in setFrame